# I want to add custom radio button (value defined by user)

Tags: javascript, php

I have four radio buttons on my page. The value of three radio buttons is predefined.

I want to customize the fourth radio button by providing text box in front of it. User has to fill the text box if s/he selects the fourth radio button and the value is sent as radio button value.

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">

Donation:
<input type="radio" name="donation" <?php if (isset($donation) && $donation=="20,000") echo "checked";?>  value="20,000">20,000
<input type="radio" name="donation" <?php if (isset($donation) && $donation=="10,000") echo "checked";?>  value="10,000">10,000
<input type="radio" name="donation" <?php if (isset($donation) && $donation=="5,000") echo "checked";?>  value="5,000">5,000
<input type="radio" name="donation" <?php if (isset($donation) && $donation=="$custom") echo "checked";?>  value="$custom"><input type="text" name="custom" value="<?php echo $custom;?>">Not less than Rs. 3000
<span class="error">* <?php echo $donationErr;?></span>
<br><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">


<?php
echo "<h2>Your Input:</h2>";

echo "<br>";
echo $donation;
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

**HTML**

```
<input type= "radio" name ="radiostemp" value="" rel=""/>
<input type= "radio" name ="radiostemp" value="" rel=""/>
<input type= "radio" name ="radiostemp" value="" rel=""/>
<input type= "radio" name ="radiostemp" value="" rel="attach" />
<input type="text" value="" id="testtype" />
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input[type=radio]").change(function(){
        if($(this).attr("rel") == "attach")
        {
            $(this).val($("#testtype").val());
        }
    });

   $("#testtype").change(function(){
        $("input[type=radio]:eq(3)").val($(this).val());
   });   
});
```

Comment: Also add a textbox `change` to update the radio. My vote for you :)